# How to print a block in node.tpl.php only for admin?

Tags: 7, theming

What is the simplest code that checks if user is admin and then prints a block to that user in node.tpl.php? I have seen different examples, but they are all either complicated and deal with other problems at the same time or they include editing template.php, which I want to avoid. I have tried with this, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php if ($is_admin->true): ?>
<?php print views_embed_view('myview','block'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there such a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Tried this module: Block Access [link](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_access)

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
global $user;
if (in_array('admin', $user->roles)) {  //if not "admin", maybe "administrator"?

}
```

Or you can use the built-in block access control, under your block's configuration you'll see "Visibility Settings" and in there is a way to restrict by user role.

Edit: what the hell, it's friday and I'm bored.

Take this in small steps before you conclude it's "not working".

Step 1)

```
global $user;
if (in_array('admin', $user->roles)) {  //if not "admin", maybe "administrator"?
    echo "<hr>admin user!<hr>";
}
```

If that works, then start making it more complex.  This is the best way to learn how to do new things, especially with PHP since you get to see your stuff immediately!

Comment: Block settings are easy, but I have to use tpl.php in this case. Where exactly do I specify here that it should work for admin only?

Comment: just put in the name of the role you want, so in this case 'admin'  (I think it's shortened, might be "administrator")

Comment: Please keep in mind that I'm really not good with php. :) I have edited the question, is that it?

Comment: look at my edit :)

in_array($needle, $haystack)

Comment: OK, tried it, but it didn't output anything. You can see the whole code at the bottom of the question. I have tried both admin and administrator.

Comment: see my new edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing, it doesn't output anything either.

Comment: okay... so I wasn't sure if it was "admin" or "administrator"... try the long form.   these are the sorts of troubleshooting steps you have to think about when doing programming work.

Comment: Long form? :) Never mind, I'll try to find a workaround. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php global $user; ?>
<?php if ($user->roles[5]): ?>
<?php print views_embed_view('myview','block'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

just make sure of the role number from **admin/people/permissions/roles** hover the link on your Administrator **edit role** you'll see the number of the role at the end of the link